# MVC C# Validate information against database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

We have a form that you can put in manually.  This form ties into a customer.  I was tasked to write a validator that checks to see if a unique identifier is changed, that is checks the database, checks the customer, and if the unique identifier is different than the one that is put in to spit out an error.  I already have a list of extra validation errors on my view model so I figured I would just use this.  Right now my view models just look at strings and proper formats.  How would I go about comparing information from what is input to what is in the database.  If you need anymore information please tell me and I will provide it.  Thank you.

**View Model**

```
public IList<string> MailInExtraValidationErrors()
        {
            var retval = new List<string>();

            Validators.ValidateString(retval, Comments, "The Comments field", false, 2000);

            Validators.ValidateString(retval, FirstName, "First Name", false, 50);
            Validators.ValidateString(retval, LastName, "Last Name", false, 50);
            Validators.ValidateString(retval, BusinessName, "Business Name", false, 200);

            Phone = Validators.ValidatePhone(retval, Phone, "Phone Number", false);
            Validators.ValidateEmail(retval, Email, "Email Address", false, 150);

            retval.AddRange(MailingAddress.ExtraValidationErrors(Constants.mailing, true));
            if (!SameAsMailing && PhysicalAddress != null)
            {
                retval.AddRange(PhysicalAddress.ExtraValidationErrors(Constants.physical, true));
            }

            return retval;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a malicious user from changing id's while its embedded on a webpage?

Comment: what validation framework is this?  some home grown one?

Comment: I inherited this code from the previous coder, so I am unsure if it's homegrown or not I assume it is.  We are trying to prevent a person to change a unique id who is already in the system.

Comment: The more I look at this code yes, it has to be home grown.

Comment: What is the unique id you are trying to preserve and what value does the customer enter which is uniquely identifying them?  The email address?

Comment: It's an account number, so numbers with dashes.  It will be a string.  I also have a IRepository which I will need to pass in as a parameter I think...